# Django where autoblocks data is stored?

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-cms

I am working on online shop project. I have product model and it has description field, but it's empty. Description data is stored somehow with django-cms and autoblocks. I can edit that description in browser with django-cms. In the template this `{% autoblock product.slug %}` line is description.

In views.py, i pass `product` as context, but it's slug field has nothing to do with description, when i try `{{ product.slug }}`.

Also googled about Autoblocks, but only what managed to find out it's this model:

```
class Autoblock(models.Model):
    composite_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = PlaceholderField('content')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.composite_id
```

All of these fields has nothing to do with description.

So my question is, how can i access that description in code?

Comment: Why are you even using that *piece-of-crap* cms, man? You'd be better off programming your project in *plain* Django.

Comment: Give me arguments why it is piece-of-crap?